# Is there any other way to add attributes to a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Is there any way to add attributes to the Welcome function-component, other than by creating a separate line such as `<Welcome name="Sara" />`?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can render the elements of an array as:

```
function App() {
  const elements = ["Sara", "Cahal", "Edite"]

  return (
    <div>
      { elements.map((e, i) => <Welcome key={i} name={e} />) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Additionally I suggest to read through the documentation of [Rendering Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) and [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not the standard way of defining props, but I quite like the syntax of using an object with the spread operator to define props if you have variables with the names of the props you want.

```
function App() {
  const elements = ['Sara', 'Cahal', 'Edite'];

  return (
    <div>
      {elements.map((name, key) => (
        <Welcome {...{ name, key }} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with names and after loop through it:

```
const names = ["Sara", "Cahal", "Edite"];

return (
    <div>
        {names.map(name => <Welcome key={name} name={name} />)}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Would key={name} be necessary? Thanks a lot btw

Comment: yes it's necessary. Also avoid situations when you use mapped item index/key as a key.  You can read more about it here:  https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c#:~:text=The%20reason%20is%20because%20you,just%20the%20content%20is%20changed.